# How to write a hierarchical logic expression next to a picture?

Tags: logic

How to write a hierarchical logic expression (as attached) next to a picture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by next to a picture? Your question is very unclear as it stands. Which is the 'hierarchical expression'? (Do you mean a hierarchy of expressions?) Which is the picture?

Comment: Off-topic: the diagram appears to be logical nonsense, given the usual interpretation of symbols as operators and atomic formulae.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/trees/

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! You could use `forest` to draw this tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={math content,calign=fixed edge angles}
[\land
 [p]
 [\lor
  [\lnot
   [q]
  ]
  [r]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={math content,s sep+=1.5em}
[\land
 [p]
 [\lor
  [\lnot
   [q]
  ]
  [r]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]